# Selenium IDE: How to tell if a user clicked Cancel on a scripted Prompt?

Tags: selenium-ide, prompt

This seems like a very basic question, but just can't figure it out...

I am using a prompt to collect input parameters from my users during script execution with the following line:

```
|storeEval|prompt("How many test users would you like to create?")|dataHowMany|
```

and this works fine to collect the number. But...

**Question:** How do I tell if the user clicked the **Cancel** button (regardless of entering data or not) instead of the **OK** button? If they click Cancel I want to be able to gotoif and end the execution.

I have tried playing with assertConfirmation and assertPrompt, but they do not seem to be the commands I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that I've got the idea of your question. But if I am right here is the answer:

You need [Selenium IDE flow control extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flow-control/) to do it.

```
storeEval | prompt("How many test users would you like to create?") | dataHowMany
gotoIf    | ${dataHowMany}==null | ENDOFTEST
.....
.....#Your test here
.....
label     | ENDOFTEST
```

Comment: What if a value was entered into the field dataHowMany (without submitting) and then Cancel was clicked. Wouldn't that make ${dataHowMany} not null?